# Confusion related to expectation

Tags: expected-value

I was reading a paper related to minimaxity.

[image]

If $\hat{\theta}$ is the estimate of an unknown parameter $\theta$ and $l(\hat\theta-\theta)$ is the loss function they have mentioned $E_p$ is the mean of $l(\hat\theta-\theta)$ under distribution P. I didn't get this part. If $\hat\theta$ is an estimate and $\theta$ is the unknown parameter of a distribution P, then $\theta$ is fixed since it is the mean of the distribution P which is not known. So what is meant by expectation of $l(\hat\theta-\theta)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The estimator $\hat{\theta}$ is a function of $n$ random variables $X_1,...,X_n$. A sample is a realisation of these variables. The composition of measurable functions (random variables) is again measurable. For this reason, it makes sense to assign a probability distribution to $\hat{\theta}$.

For example, if $\hat{\theta}=\bar{x}=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n x_j$ and $x_j\sim N(\mu,1)$, then $\hat{\theta}\sim N(\mu,n^{-1/2})$.

In general, if $\hat{\theta}\sim F$, then $E[l(\theta-\hat{\theta})]=\int l(\theta-\hat{\theta}) dF(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\theta$ is fixed, as you say, but its estimate $\hat{\theta}$ will be a function of the data, as the authors say, & is therefore a random variable; functions of $\hat{\theta}$ are therefore random variables, with interesting expectations.